# Query in Marklogic DB to filter documents for the last 24 hours

Tags: marklogic

Is there a way to filter out documents in marklogic based on a date field?

Something like:

```
select * from data-hub-STAGING where load_date > '2022-01-12'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to issue such a query, as long as there is a date or dateTime being tracked and indexed.

For any MarkLogic database, there is a [database option](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/databases#id_77652) to enable "**maintain last modified**", which will set and maintain a document property `prop:last-modified` that can be indexed and range-queries applied.

Your example table was "data-hub-STAGING". If you are using a MarkLogic Data Hub, the **datahubCreatedOn** field is available with a `dateTime` range index.

https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.6/flows/about-flows.html#about-flows__pre_ay4_frh_ypb

> For every content object outputted by a Data Hub step, regardless of the step type, Data Hub will add the following document metadata keys and values to the document wrapped by the content object:
>
> - **datahubCreatedOn** = the date and time at which the document is written

Of course, any other date/dateTime element, JSON field, or document property can also be indexed and then used to filter docs as well.

Then the appropriate [range query](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/rangequery) can be applied to a search in JavaScript, XQuery, Optic, SQL, etc.

For example, in JavaScript searching by field `datahubCreatedOn` with [`cts.fieldRangeQuery()`](https://api.marklogic.com/cts.fieldRangeQuery):

```
cts.search(cts.fieldRangeQuery("datahubCreatedOn", ">", 
  new Date(Date.now() - 86400 * 1000).toISOString()))
```

and in XQuery searching by `prop:last-modified` with [`cts:element-range-query()`](https://api.marklogic.com/cts:element-range-query):

```
cts:search(doc(), cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("prop:last-modified"), ">",
 current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration("-PT24H")))
```

You should even be able to execute the SQL in your question, if you were to create a SQL [Template View](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/creating-template-views).